# Disable Alt+Home in IE11 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have been able to disable some browser hotkeys using Javascript but it seems that IE11 will not let me disable Alt+Home (see example code below). Any idea why this does not work in IE11?

```
jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

    // Stop Browser History (ctrl + H)

    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 72) {

        return false;

    }

    // Stop Alt + Home

    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 36) {

        return false;
    }
...
```

Comment: While this is less relevant since you're using IE11, you may want to look at [MDN's page on keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) if you plan on exposing this code to other browsers.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are implemented by the OS and Browser. You can't augment the functionality of the Browser or the OS via JavaScript in a webpage. At most, you can intercept keypress events on the page and stop those events from propagating inside the page but not at a browser/os level.

Comment: this is not possible in ie11, Alt is tied too much with the browser and windows. the only way to stop that is by putting an alert statement or prompt.

Comment: Thanks @karthick! I eventually came to this conclusion, looks like adding an alert will do the trick!

Comment: Electron app would allow you otherwise probably no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in IE11, by adding an alert() call.

```
jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

// Stop Alt + Home
if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 36) {
    alert("Your message here");
    return false;
}
```